# Calculating number of days where a condition is met over multiple regions in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, filter, function, average, reduceregion

I have been trying to **calculate the number of days where the wind speed average per day exceeded 25 m/s for all municipalities in Colombia** during the year 2015. My goal is to know how many days helicopters were able to fly during that year. Certainly, hourly data would be more accurate, but computation time was already too high for this task with daily data. I have tried to do the following, but I get this error message: *Dictionary (Error). The service is currently unavailable.*

```
var fao = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2")
var gldas = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H");

// Filter Colombia from Worldwide dataset
var colombia = fao.filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Colombia'));
var municipalities = colombia.select('ADM1_NAME','ADM2_NAME')
    
//Mapping municipalities of Colombia
Map.setCenter(-75, 6, 5);
var styleParams = {
    fillColor: '#ccffff',
    color: '#000099',
    width: 1.0,
 };
    
var dataset = municipalities.style(styleParams);
Map.addLayer(dataset, {}, 'Colombias Second Level Administrative Units');
    
// Function to obtain the images where windspeed <= 25 for safe flight conditions
var daysMeetingConditionImage = function (image) {
// Masked-off pixels will not be counted.
   return image.updateMask(
   image.select('Wind_f_inst')
   .lte(25)
   .selfMask()// Updates new mask values
   );
}
    
// Setting begin date and end date as variables and filter from ImageCollection
var begin = ee.Date.fromYMD(2015,1,1);
var end = ee.Date.fromYMD(2015,1,31);
var select_gldas = gldas.filterDate(begin,end);
    
// Apply function to filtered Image Collection and 
var clear_days = select_gldas.map(daysMeetingConditionImage);
var count = clear_days.reduce(ee.Reducer.sum());
    
print(count.reduceRegion({
      reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
      geometry: municipalities,
      scale : 30,
      maxPixels: 1e13,
      tileScale: 10
      }))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't actually find any occurrence where the wind speed was larger then `25 m/s` in 2015 in Colombia. The max value was `15.6 m/s`:

https://code.earthengine.google.com/f950e2211be6b75519553a0003281ea8

The reason your script is failing is probably that you're running `reduceRegion()` at `30 m` scale for the whole of Colombia. You will need to increase the scale, or export these results. The good thing is that your data set isn't in `30 m` to begin with, but in `27830 m`. So increasing the scale makes perfect sense.

Here's my stab at implementing something like you're asking for, using a lower threshold to get some non-clear days:

```
var windSpeedThreshold = 5
var startYear = 2000
var endYear = 2016 // Exclusive
var aoi = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL/2015/level2")
  .filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM0_NAME', 'Colombia'))
  .geometry()

var meanClearDaysCounts = ee.FeatureCollection(
  ee.List.sequence(startYear, ee.Number(endYear).subtract(1))
    .map(toClearDaysCountMean)
)

print(meanClearDaysCounts.aggregate_array('clear_days'))

// For debugging
// Map.addLayer(toClearDaysCountImage(2015), {min: 0, max: 366, palette: '#FD3000, #FF8410, #FCC228, #B3C120, #4DA910, #1E7D83, #0034F5'}, 'clearDaysCount')


function toClearDaysCountImage(year) {
  var start = ee.Date.fromYMD(year, 1, 1)
  var end = start.advance(1, 'year')
  var windSpeedCollection = ee.ImageCollection("NASA/GLDAS/V021/NOAH/G025/T3H")
    .select('Wind_f_inst')
  return ee.ImageCollection(
    ee.List.sequence(0, end.difference(start, 'days').subtract(1))
      .map(function (dayOffset) {
        var date = start.advance(ee.Number(dayOffset), 'days')
        return windSpeedCollection
          .filterDate(date, date.advance(1, 'day'))
          // Daily max instead of mean perhaps? 
          // Unable to fly at any point during the day 
          .max() 
          .lte(windSpeedThreshold)
          .selfMask()
      })
  ).reduce(ee.Reducer.count()).rename('clear_days')
}

function toClearDaysCountMean(year) {
  var clearDaysCount = toClearDaysCountImage(year)
  var clearDaysCountMean = clearDaysCount.reduceRegion({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    geometry: aoi,
    scale: 27830, // You ran this in 30 meters, but the imagery has a resolution of 27830m
    maxPixels: 1e13
  })
  return ee.Feature(null, clearDaysCountMean)
    .set('year', year)
}
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/0256434cad41567357569f228f764628

Comment: This actually solved 95% of my question, I am just having trouble modifying the second function "toClearDaysCountMean" to use the reduceRegions and not the reduceRegion option, as I want to obtain the 2nd level administrative units of Colombia, so, I need the yearly count per municipality. Any suggestions about this?

Comment: https://code.earthengine.google.com/279162d6c81ebc2c36bc5cff8cefd700

Comment: Thank you sooooo much!!! This is exactly what I needed :)

Comment: I forgot to include the number of days: https://code.earthengine.google.com/8d605071a60bfcc6ab464e8787789b74

Comment: I think that you have some days in some regions without any data at all (maybe cloud? I don't know how this product is generated). This gives the impression that you have days you cannot fly. That's something you might want to take into account.

Comment: I will definitely take that info into consideration and will use the 2nd script. Thanks so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Not a maps related solution, but more an "aeronautical" one. You can try to reach Aeronautica Civil or IDEAM and ask them for the METAR reports. I'm sure you know what they are, but for other forum visitors, these are the meteorological reports that the pilots require before and during flight.

For the Colombian case, this is an example
http://www.meteoaeronautica.gov.co/consulta-metar

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will definitely use it to confront my results, nevertheless, I need county-level aggregated results per year from 2000-2016.